# How to reference JSX component props from array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have JSX components in an array, and want to reference their props and state by accessing them in the array.

```
let default = [
    <Space name="1" />,
    <Space name="2" color="#ffffff" />
]

let selected = default[0];
```

This gives me the error `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` when trying to access the name prop I have set by doing `selected.name`.

I also tried using an array of regular objects (`[new Space('1', '#ffffff'), etc]`) and rendering them with a map, but while this let me access props from the array directly, I couldn't access the props from the render method.

I'm new to react so any help is appreciated.

Comment: to access a component you need to specify a `ref`. But components instance has props exposed via a props key. So you would have to do `this.myRef.current.props.name` assuming the ref was created with `createRef`

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. What are you trying to do that requires accessing the properties like that?

Comment: @Herohtar I'm trying to create Monopoly, and the way I'm trying to get info about where the player lands is by doing this: 
```let currentSpace = defaultProperties[this.state.position];
    console.log(this.props.name + ' landed on ' + currentSpace.name + ' which is ' + (currentSpace.owned ? 'owned by ' + currentSpace.owner.name : 'unowned'));```

Comment: Sounds like you should probably just be storing the space details as plain objects and then using those to render the components, and when you need to get the details you can just access them from the object array as intended. `defaultProperties.map(item => <Space name={item.name} color={item.color} ...)` or even `<Space {...item} />`

Comment: @Herohtar I was doing that, but then in the render method for the properties I wasn't able to access any of the props I passed through. With regular JSX you name your props (name=" ", price=" ", etc) but with a class/object its just `new Property(' ', ' ', ' ')` which I then can't access. I couldn't find anything on the internet about how to access these props. Do I just have to not pass the props through the constructor the way react wants me to and just do it the regular JS way?

Comment: I mean literally a plain object... `defaultProperties = [{name: 1}, {name: 2, color: "#ffffff"}]`. You don't need to construct a class or anything; the component construction is done in the `map` (see previous comment)

Comment: OH, I see now. I'll try this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this are: Separate this two things. Declare an Array of objects likes this: `const default = [{name: "Godzilla Firefox"}, {name: "Metallica"}]` or not objects: `const default = ["Samsung", "Apple"]`. Then, you can make a map in the Array. `const data = default.map(value ⇒ <Space key={value} name={value} />)`. Like this you can easily access the values. So, put in your render method the `{data}`. It's will be re-render every time as you change.